# why doesn't basic auth work with a simple nginx return Statement?

Tags: nginx

I have server configured this way:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  location /health {
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file "/etc/nginx/.htpasswd";

    default_type application/json;
    return 200 '{"status":"Ok"}';
  }
}
```

`/etc/nginx/.htpasswd` exists and contains desired credentials.
Now when I try to access this location it just passes all requests without auth check. E.g.:

```
➜  ~ curl http://localhost:23456/health
{"status":"Ok"}%
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you are not "missing" something in general but there is a but :)

NGINX works with something called "access-phases". `return` kicks in VERY VERY VERY early in the request processing. Having a `return` statement in a location block tells NGINX to immediately return with this. No matter whats in  other phases after it.

Further reading: http://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html#http_phases

```
NGX_HTTP_SERVER_REWRITE_PHASE — Phase where rewrite directives defined in a server block (but outside a location block) are processed. The ngx_http_rewrite_module installs its handler at this phase.
```

As the `return` statement is part of the `ngx_http_rewrite_module` this is the phase where the return statement kicks in. According to the documentation the `NGX_HTTP_ACCESS_PHASE`  in which your `auth_basic` will be checked comes a lot later.

So to make this work you have to use a little trick.

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  location /health {
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file "/etc/nginx/.htpasswd";
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
  }
}

server {
  listen 8080;

  location /{
    default_type application/json;
    return 200 '{"status":"Ok"}';
  }
}
```

Or you can use `njs` with a `js_content` as well if you do not want to use a proxy.

Comment: thank you for such detailed answer, I confirm proposed solution works.

Answer (score 3):

As the accepted answer already states, there is no clean solution to this. However, there's an alternative workaround that doesn't require an additional server block:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  location /health {
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file "/etc/nginx/.htpasswd";
    try_files /dev/null @real_health;
  }

  location @real_health {
    default_type application/json;
    return 200 '{"status":"Ok"}';
  }
}
```