# RSelenium Enter User details in prompt

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

I use RSelenium to connect to an internal website that asks for user login via a prompt like this: [image: example image]

(note that the URL=red bar is redacted)

Connecting to the Selenium Server and accessing the website works, but I cannot access the user prompt and therefore cannot login.

Is there any way I can provide user and pw to the prompt using RSelenium?

I use the code like so:

Note that for testing purposes you can use this URL: https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth with admin admin.

```
library(RSelenium)
sel <- list(addr = "THE-SELENIUM-IP", port = 4444)

dr <- remoteDriver(
  remoteServerAddr = sel$addr,
  port = sel$port
)
res <- dr$open()

full_url <- "https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth"
dr$navigate(full_url)
```

using `dr$screenshot(display = TRUE)` I receive this error `Dismissed user prompt dialog: This site is asking you to sign in`

Alternatively, I can try to define User and PW in the url like so:

```
user <- "MYUSER"
pw <- "MYPASSWORD@123"

full_url <- paste0("http://", user, ":", URLencode(pw, reserved = TRUE), "@https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth")

dr$navigate(full_url)
dr$screenshot(display = TRUE)
```

But I get the same error.

Note that this is a prompt and not part of the HTML website (ie I cannot `findElementBy(...)` and insert values like could with pure HTML elements).

### Edit - another unsuccessful attempt

I also tried this following [this](https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/basic-http-authentication):

```
user <- "MYUSER"
pw <- "MYPASSWORD@123"

script <- glue::glue(
  "browserstack_executor: {\"action\": \"sendBasicAuth\", \"arguments\": {\"username\": \"{{user}}\", \"password\": \"{{pw}}\", \"timeout\": \"1000\"}}",
  .open = "{{", .close = "}}"
)
dr$executeScript(script)
```

but I get the error: `Dismissed user prompt dialog: This site is asking you to sign in`.

### Edit 2 - Docker website for MWE

If you want to create a simple web app with basic auth for debugging, you can use the following docker image and command:

file `nginx.conf`

```
# see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/67981564/3048453
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  location / {
    default_type text/plain;
    return 200 "Welcome";
  }
  location /auth {
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file "/etc/nginx/.htpasswd";
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
  }
}
server {
  listen 8080;
  location / {
    default_type text/plain;
    return 200 "AUTHENTICATED";
  }
}
```

file `Dockerfile`

```
FROM nginx:1.23.1
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apache2-utils && mkdir -p etc/nginx && htpasswd -c -B -b /etc/nginx/.htpasswd user password
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
RUN service nginx restart
```

Command to start the container: `docker build -t nginx-so-tester . && docker run --rm -p 80:80 nginx-so-tester`

And then you can visit `http://localhost/auth`. The credentials are `user` and `password`.

## Edit 3 - GUI of Remote Docker Instance

While debugging this problem, I setup a docker instance to which I can connect to and look at what is happening on the browser side.

I start a docker selenium instance with `docker run --rm -p 4444:4444 -p 7900:7900 --shm-size="2g" selenium/standalone-firefox:103.0` and then connect from RSelenium to it with:

```
dr <- remoteDriver(
  remoteServerAddr = "localhost",
  port = 4444L
)
dr$open()
```

at the same time I open my browser to `localhost:7900` and provide the password `secret` (default pw by selenium) and connect to the VNC and see the following:

[image: example image 2]

When I navigate to the problematic URL like so

```
url <- "http://my.redacted-url.com"
dr$navigate(url)
```

I see the following in the VNC browser:

[image: ex image 3]

I also tried to use `dr$sendKeysToAlert(list("user", keys = "TAB", "password", keys = "ENTER"))` but get a 401 (ie the authorization didnt work because the credentials where not pasted correctly to the form, I guess).

Comment: How do you expect us to debug this without url

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share the URL and even if I could you could not access it as it is an internal system. Ill try to create an nginx docker image as soon as I find the time.

Comment: @GABDA, I have added a MWE using docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debugging, we were able to change the webserver of the service to allow for the credentials in the URL (I had no idea that there are webservers that do not allow this).

That is, the solution is now this:

```
library(RSelenium)

# start and connect to the selenium server as shown in the question...
dr <- remotDriver(
  ...,
  # note that we also had to allow insecure certificates due to the setup of an internal network
  # avoid if possible
  extraCapabilities = list("acceptInsecureCerts" = TRUE)
)

user <- "admin"
pw <- "admin"

full_url <- paste0("http://", user, ":", URLencode(pw, reserved = TRUE), "@https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth")

dr$navigate(full_url)
dr$screenshot(display = TRUE)
```